# Excel : Pivot table not able to get desired result

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table that needs to be used for historical data load. I need the data to be pivoted in order to insert into MySQL database table. I tried to do the pivoting in the excel but I do not get any values in the result after the pivot.

I tried pivoting the data using a pivot table from the Insert menu and kept desired columns but in row data, I cannot produce any values.

see screenshot here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ave_-9o8DQVEfZxNT2ovA3LkiMg

Here is the link for sample data and expected result. https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ave_-9o8DQVEeMY-sbKCcG9n2HU

Thanks and Regards,
Success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question in M code

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\path\Need to Pivot.xlsx")),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    notNull = Table.SelectRows(Sheet1_Sheet, each [Column1] <> null),
    tables = Table.Split(notNull,8),
    transform = List.Transform(tables, each Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.FillDown(Table.Transpose(_),{"Column1"}))),
    rename = List.Transform(transform, each Table.RenameColumns(_, {{Table.ColumnNames(_){0},"Date"}, {"SensorName", "Time"}})),
    combine = Table.Combine(rename),
    types = Table.TransformColumnTypes(combine,{"Time", type time})
in
    types
```